# Hashicorp Vault Artifactory Secrets Plugin error

Tags: artifactory, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to add Vault Artifactory Secrets Plugin to the vault catalog, by following the below link.
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Hashicorp+Vault+Artifactory+Secrets+Plugin

I executed the below command to register the plugin in the Vault server's plugin catalog

```
vault write sys/plugins/catalog/secret/artifactory \
    sha_256="$(sha256sum /etc/vault.d/plugins/artifactory-secrets-plugin_v0.1.2 | cut -d " " -f 1)" \
    command="artifactory"
```

But I get below error

```
Error writing data to sys/plugins/catalog/secret/artifactory: Error making API request.
URL: PUT http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/plugins/catalog/secret/artifactory
Code: 500. Errors:
* 1 error occurred:
        * error while validating the command path: lstat /etc/vault.d/plugins/artifactory: no such file or directory
```

I have used the pre-built artifactory plugin from the below GitHub path 
artifactory-secrets-plugin_v0.1.2 
https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-secrets-plugin/releases

```
vault --version
Vault v1.12.0 (558abfa75702b5dab4c98e86b802fb9aef43b0eb), built 2022-10-10T18:14:33Z
```

vault config file -

```
cat /etc/vault/config.hcl
disable_cache = true
disable_mlock = true
storage "file" {
  path    = "/var/lib/vault/data"
  node_id = "node1"
}

listener "tcp" {
  address     = "127.0.0.1:8200"
  tls_disable = "true"
}

api_addr = "http://127.0.0.1:8200"
cluster_addr = "https://127.0.0.1:8201"
ui = true
plugin_directory = "/etc/vault.d/plugins/"
```

I referred a few GitHub issues but couldn't see any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ah! this issue is now resolved for me.
We just need to provide the command with the plugin name `artifactory-secrets-plugin_v0.1.2`

```
vault write sys/plugins/catalog/secret/artifactory \
    sha_256="$(sha256sum /etc/vault.d/plugins/artifactory-secrets-plugin_v0.1.2 | cut -d " " -f 1)" \
    command="artifactory-secrets-plugin_v0.1.2"

Success! Data written to: sys/plugins/catalog/secret/artifactory
```

Then just enable the artifactory secret engine.

```
vault secrets enable artifactory

Success! Enabled the artifactory secrets engine at: artifactory/
```